# Customize Total Section In Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, cart, quote, grand-total

How can I customise the Total calculation so that it will calculate only the price of certain products with some specific attribute value?

I tried by re-creating `Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Subtotal.php` and inserted my attribute value condition inside the collect method foreach.

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
        if($this->_product->load($item->getProductId())->getData('product_store_type') == 214)
        {
             ...
        }
       }
```

But not working !! Still it shows sum of all products price in total.

Any Suggestions or Opinions?

*Brief Description about the Project Requirement:*

I have two different domain stores. But they can share their cart details. So that I can add products from both the sites and checkout together. Now, First store uses redeem points instead of currencies and the second store uses USD.

I am using a store_type attribute value to change the Price format to "Points" in the frontend pages.

So In my checkout cart page order summary section, I need to show subtotal (USD) & subtotal (points) separately. No Grand total will be there. The same in the mini cart also.

[image]

Comment: `calculate only the price of certain products with some specific attribute value` what u mean by it? The product which does not  have this specific attribute then this product  cart attribute does not show at   total?

Comment: @AmitBera: I mean I have two different domain stores. But they can share their cart details. So that I can add products from both the sites and checkout together. Now, First store uses redeem points instead of currencies and the second store uses USD. I can distinguish it using a store_type attribute.  So In my checkout page, i need to show subtotal (USD) & subtotal (points) separately. No Grand total will be there. I hope now you got an idea on what I meant

Comment: @AmitBera: I have updated my question as well.

Comment: Try using `$item->getProduct()` instead of `$this->_product->load($item->getProductId())`

Comment: @AaronAllen : Hi Aaron.I'm getting quote item product attribute values and all.. what I'm struggling is to change the Subtotal value.